# PVID for hp switch 1910

Tags: vlan, hp

I am configuring layer 2 vlans between 3com 4200 switch and an hp 1910, I set the uplinks as trunk ports on both vlans.
In 3com I set the pvid to permit all vlans but in 1910 how can I permit all vlans, does it permit them by default since on the port detail for the uplink its showing vlan 1 as the pvid, If I add another vlan I can no more access the switch.
So how can I permit all other vlans?

I have port 44 to 47 untagged members of vlan 10 and all other ports belong to vlan 1. so how will be the configuration.
Currently all what I did is set the linktype to trunk on both uplinks.
On the 3com switch I permit all vlans on uplink on hp its only permitted vlan 1, I want to also permit vlan 10 to communicate with vlan 10 on 3com switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the 1910, you can't simply "permit all VLAN IDs". You need to create each VLAN and assign it as tagged or untagged to the interfaces as required (creating all VLANs first and then assigning them to the ports as a second step is advisable).

For instance, if port 1 is your trunk port and 44-47 are access ports associated with VLAN 10 you would assign VLAN 10 as tagged on port 1 and untagged on ports 44-47.

Additionally, you need to make sure you can connect to the management VLAN at all times. If you need to move it from untagged/native to tagged on the uplink, configure it as tagged on the 1910 first and then on the uplink (you lose management connectivity in between).

Comment: Sorry Zac but I didn't understand your answer. I have two vlans on switch 1910 and 3com which are default vlan 1 and vlan 10, I have 4 ports on vlan 10 port 44 to 47. You mean set those 4 ports as tagged to vlan 10 and they will be permitted to pass on trunk?

Comment: You don't tag VLANs on access ports, only on trunks. Tag VLAN 10 on the trunk port and untag it on the client port(s). For a more detailed answer you'd need to tell us which ports go where. Please add details to your question and I'll add details to the answer.

Comment: I mean I don't need tp pvid vlan 10 on the uplink trunk port since I created vlan 10 already and assigned untagged ports on the two switches?

Comment: If the VLAN isn't assigned as tagged on the trunk port, frames from that VLAN won't be able to cross the trunk.

Comment: How would I tag them on the trunk?

Comment: Check [the manual](http://h20628.www2.hp.com/km-ext/kmcsdirect/emr_na-c03586669-2.pdf) - *Network -> VLAN -> Modify Port*, enter the VLAN ID, select *Tagged*, select the ports where it is to be tagged.